# android library for sending photos and videos via email

Tags: java, android, ios, email

I'm trying to create an android mobile application, which the users can use in order to send images, videos, or audio files via email which are represented as a line of thumbnails. My initial implementation was to use a scroll-view and add an image-view every time a picture was selected. A scroll-view like this helps scroll across the thumbnails which don't fit on the screen. The only problem is that I am not so sure that videos or audio files can be placed in a scroll-view. The main problem is that those captured photos, videos have no variable name therefore I can't send them by email as there are no references. I was wondering if there is any alternative library in Java that can handle these problems for both photos and videos, which are:

```
1- scroll through the Images, videos or audio files thumbnails in case they don't fit in the screen.
2- give each captured photo, video a unique reference which I can use later for sending these photos, videos via email. <br>
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should work with an adapter (if you are not familiar with adapters, check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html)

through this, you can get a list of all files of a specific path. You can list the files and add for every file an onclicklistener. The onclicklistener can then start the mail application with

```
File file = new File(PATH_OF_FOLDER + File.separator + <name of the file you clicked>
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
try {
// try to start the emailActivity
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail..."));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
  //auto-generated
}
```